# Recurring REST call inside ionic page

Tags: angular, ionic2

In an Ionic page I need to display a qrCode until a rest call to the server return an ack value.
I need to do that call every one or five seconds in order to check the "activation done" phase.

How can I start that recurring call when I enter the page and do it continuosly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start pinging API onInit()

```
ngOnInit(){    
   this.pingAPI().subscribe(
     (data) => {
        // activate QR code
     }
   ); 
}

private pingAPI(){
         return Observable.timer(1000, 5000)          // after 1 second, tick every 5 second
                    .map(() => {
                        return callAPI().map(
                               (data) => {
                                  // manipulate data
                                  return data;
                               }
                        );
                    })
                    // do not go further unless the property 'activationDone' is truthy
                    .filter(data=> data.activationDone == true)
                    .first();  // stop the chain when condition satisfies for the first time
}
```

Comment: If my "callAPI()" is an Observable<T>, how do I have to write the map?

Comment: In the same way how you write map, it is not different here. updated answer.